# i want to send error message through php get method if user already exists in database but then reset the url without GET variable

Tags: javascript, php

After getting the error message through url i am throwing an error message through p tag

and then using window.location.pushstate({}, "Hide", "http://localhost/shravari/project1/register.html") method to have a clean url without the error message

this is my php code

```
header('Location:../register.html?error=1');
```

this is my javascript code

```
var currentUrl = $(location).attr('href');  
    if (currentUrl.match(/error=1/g)) {
       $('#erroru').html('User already exists, please <a href="login.html">login</a> to access the page');
        $('#erroru').css('color','red');
        $('#erroru').css('text-algin','center');
        // window.location.assign('http://localhost/shravari/project1/register.html'); 
        window.history.pushState({}, "Hide", "http://localhost/shravari/project1/register.html");

    }
```

the window.location.assign('http://localhost/shravari/project1/register.html'); works very well on mac system that is the error is displayed in p tag and the url don't hold the get method error variable but doesn't work on windows

and the  window.history.pushState({}, "Hide", "http://localhost/shravari/project1/register.html"); works on windows system that is the error is displayed in p tag and the url don't hold the get method error variable but doesn't work on mac
And in both the systems i used chrome

Comment: Why don't you just use Ajax? Then you won't need to care about the URL and can return what ever data you need.

Comment: If you don't want to have the error message as part of the URL, then why do redirect the browser there? That makes little sense. The error message replaces the content that would be replied if no error occurs. That error message can be evaluated and the client itself decides what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

use php session.

you can define session as a session_start();

then after you can send error message through the session

ex : $_SESSION['error'] = "your error message";